# Why not say Shir Shel Yom in the evening?

Tags: tefilla, calendar, shir-shel-yom

I took a look at two questions:

[One](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86165/source-for-shir-shel-yom-of-the-gra/87945#87945), which focused on WHY we say Shir Shel Yom included the claim of the Chashukei Chemed in the answer, that "אבל הוא הדבר אשר דברתי דמה שאנו אומרים שיר של יום אינו משום זכר למקדש כלל, רק להזכיר מעין יצירת היום" -- the Shir commemorates some aspect of creation. This point was used to justify not saying the Shir twice in a day (morning and afternoon) but only in the morning.

The [other](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106435/what-time-of-day-was-the-world-first-created) question asked about the timing of creation and includes the idea that according to some, the world was created (at least in thought) or was declared in the evening*.

Are there any opinions that combine these and opine that the Shir Shel Yom should commemorate the creation by being said in the late afternoon/evening and NOT in the morning?

*The Rashbam does almost seem to say that the morning's coming was the completion/declaration of the day, not the beginning, but that would put the Shir at the close, not the beginning of the day. "שהעריב יום ראשון ושיקע האור, ויהי בוקר, בוקרו של לילה, שעלה עמוד השחר, הרי הושלם יום א' " so the Shir should be said in the morning, but pointing to the day that has just passed?

Comment: Possibly relevant is that we do say it at the start of _Shabas_.

Comment: @msh210 and TWICE in Shacharis on Shabbos, so the whole not saying something twice (שאין אומרים שני מזמורים ביום אחד,) goes out the window...